# Tag synonym request google-code-prettify -> prettify

Tags: support, synonym-request

I propose folding [google-code-prettify](/questions/tagged/google-code-prettify) into [prettify](/questions/tagged/prettify).

[prettify](/questions/tagged/prettify) refers to an open-source syntax highlighter: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify

> A JavaScript module and CSS file that allows syntax highlighting of source code snippets in an HTML page.

[google-code-prettify](/questions/tagged/google-code-prettify) has far fewer results, is undocumented, and refers to the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good synonym at all.

"Prettify" can act as a verb or concept which is unrelated to any product. I was able to easily find questions under [prettify](/questions/tagged/prettify) where are unrelated to any library. If somebody has managed to make the tag wiki reference a specific product, I think that is in error.

[google-code-prettify](/questions/tagged/google-code-prettify) is a *specific* product.

Comment: Would it be worthwhile editing the prettify tag description to make it less product specific.  Right now the verbiage about a JS and a CSS file seems overly specific unless referring to `prettify.{js,css}`.  I could re-tag google-code-prettify specific questions, and edit it to be a more general discussion of [tag:syntax-highlighting] and/or auto-formatting.